Query subet info of MSK cluster using AWS CDK
Is there any other way to query BrokerNodeGroupInfo.ClientSubnets of an existing MSK cluster than using lambda and custom resources? I know with that we could basically do anything, but I'd rather rely on built-in resources.
Use-case: I want to create a CDK stack that gets an MSK cluster and queries its VPC and adds public subnets to it (if not available), then launch ec2 instances backed by the public subnets where our app will live.
I'm looking for something like what is available in Terraform.

Querying existing resources is generally not supported in AWS CDK (except for fromLookup methods, whose results are cached and committed to VCS). Doing so is considered a bad practice, since a CDK app should ideally synthesize to the same cloudformation template regardless of the existing state.
